# How to design a database for multi-user flash cards?

Tags: mysql, database

some time ago, I created for my own use a flash card system; My friend liked it, so i want to make it public (online).

My version it's a quick and ugly hack that does not require a database, but a database it's needed for an web version.
I am wondering how I could design that.

item table:
item guid, question, answer, other

item "tracking table":
id, user id, item id, times wrong, last passed, next repetition, forgetting index, other

In this way, with 1000 items and 5000 users, it will make 5 millions entries.

I think that if i retrieve the data using

```
SELECT * FROM trackingtable WHERE `user-id` = 1 AND `item-id` = 1
```

it will be very slow, right?

It's the right approach?

Comment: Not right. If you have composite index that covers `user-id + item-id` columns, then this query will be fast enough.

Comment: But for each user-id + item-id there will be an unique result

Comment: Ah, i misunderstood what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an index out of the user-id and item-id columns. It will be blazing fast, even for pretty large tables. Integer comparison on indexed columns is a cheap and fast operation, especially if the index fits in memory.

Comment: Yes, string comparison is slower, mostly because strings are larger. A small index is preferable since it's easier to fit into memory. String indicies in MySQL can, however, be reduced in size by not using the entire field for indexing. Use just the first 4 or 5 characters.